# How to set the default attributes of Plots?

Tags: julia, plots.jl

In `Julia` plotting with `Plots`, I know how to set the various attributes when using `plot()` ([Attributes](https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/attributes/#attributes)).

I want to know how to set the **default attributes**, so that I don't need to set them every time.

For instance, I want to change the font-family to another one, or show the minor ticks always.

I googled but I can not find the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the way:

Use the `default()` function like so

```
using Plots
default(titlefont = (20, "times"), legendfontsize = 18, guidefont = (18, :darkgreen), tickfont = (12, :orange), guide = "x", framestyle = :zerolines, yminorgrid = true)
plot([sin, cos], -2π, 2π, label = ["sin(θ)" "cos(θ)"], title = "Trigonometric Functions", xlabel = "θ", linewidth = 2, legend = :outertopleft)
```

Taken from the documentation [here](http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/generated/gr/#gr-ref42). I know the Plots.jl docs can be a bit tricky to navigate due to their size, but in this case I just typed `default` into the doc search box.

Note that when using the `default` function you don't supply the keyword args in subsequent calls to `plot`, unless of course you want to change away from your newly specified defaults.

Since you are asking for a way to save defaults across sessions, I will also point you to this additional tip from the [installation docs](https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/install/#Initialize):

> You can override standard default values in your `~/.julia/config/startup.jl` file: `PLOTS_DEFAULTS = Dict(:markersize => 10, :legend => false, warn_on_unsupported = false)`

So here you are defining the new defaults as a dictionary which is used as an environment variable, which allows setting defaults before loading Plots (and thus without having the `default` function available).

Answer (score 2):

Store your defaults in a variable and overwrite whenever needed.

```
defs = (linestyle=:dash, linewidth=5, linecolor=:green)

plot(rand(5);defs...,linecolor=:red)
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way that I can store the `defs` in a file, so that I can just load it? For example, in jupyter/python/matplotlib, I can put a file in `~/.matplotlib/stylelib/mystyle.mplstyle`. I can just run `plt.style.use(mystyle)` to use it.

Comment: None of these suggestions seems to allow setting vector quantities whereby one might want to set colors, as in color = [:red :blue: green]. the `defs = ` method fails as does setting the environment variable `PLOTS_DEFAULTS`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to create an empty plot with all "default" attributes and then just add necessary layers each time to this empty plot.